# How to calculate the sine manually, without any rules, calculator or anything else?

Tags: trigonometry, algorithms

I want to know how to calculate the value of sin, not using table values or calculator.

I found this $\frac{(e^{ix})^2-1}{2ie^{ix}}$, but how to deal with $i$ number, if it's $\sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: Well, you could draw a right triangle containing your angle...measure the side opposite the angle and the hypotenuse and take the ratio.  I don't see how the exponential will help you...it isn't easy to compute values of that numerically either.

Comment: Maybe a truncated Taylor polynomial?

Comment: Why Do You want to do such a thing?

Comment: @lulu, I meant, is there any formula?

Comment: @ArturKlochko -- I made some small edits to your post to improve readability (at lesat, I hope it does!). If I changed anything you don't like, feel free to put it back, but I hope I've been helpful! :)

Comment: @SamT, appriciate it

Comment: No formula.  There are polynomials that approximate the value.

Comment: @lulu, I'm not good in math, I dealed with lagrange's polynom. But, as far, as I remember, I need some point's to get it

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you edited your post to explain what you are looking for.  If you just need the value of the sine of some angle, use a calculator.  That machine will inevitably use some numerical algorithms of the sort that machines are good at but people aren't (heavy iterations of elementary operations). Whatever it does is non-trivial.  If there were a trivial way to do it, people would use that.

Comment: Search tip: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:math.stackexchange.com+compute+trig+functions+by+hand

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm not sure what can you do "manually", but maybe try using a taylor approximation?
For example, you can calculate $x-\frac{x^3}{6}$

Comment: Ok, let's ask by another way: how do computers calculate $\sin(x)$ ?

Comment: Well, that's kind of the opposite of calculating manually.  
I'm not sure what computers do, but maybe they use the taylor approximation up to a certain degree they decided was accurate enough.

Comment: Don't know what Taylors approximations are, but it seems, that the only good way to get the sin value is to build a right triangle-_-

Comment: Although Taylor series (this is, finding the polynomial of degree $\leq n$ that best approximates $\sin$) would work, and perhaps there are other series that converge faster to the function, a quick google search yields the following algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC

Comment: My bad, I was assuming you took a calculus 1 class. the idea is that some functions can be represented (at least around a certain point) by an infinite sum. That's called a taylor series. you can also approximate the value instead of calculating it completely by taking the first terms of the infinite sum.
Check this list out, for some well-known taylor series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions

Comment: Ok, I tried to calculate $90-90^3/6$, and $90/180*\pi-(90/180*\pi)^3/6$ but I didn't get 0. Why?

Comment: well I kind of lied to you, the formula I gave you is only an approximation and is close to sine only for values close to 0. you can see in the plot [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(x)+-+(x+-+x%5E3%2F6)) that it is very close to sine but they grow apart as you go further away from 0. I recommend you the identities you know about sine to get to a number close to 0 and then use the formula

Comment: Now, i got a complete picture of how to calculate it. Thank You

Comment: @ArturKlochko: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395600/how-does-a-calculator-calculate-the-sine-cosine-tangent-using-just-a-number

Comment: The formula $x-(x^3/6)$ seemed to fail for $x=90$ because $x$ in this formula is supposed to be the angle measured in radians, not in degrees. So this $90-(90^3/6)$ amounted to an attempt to compute the sine of 90 radians. That, unfortunately, is way outside the range where this truncated Taylor series is anywhere near accurate.

Comment: in old games, when personal computers did not have floating-point math processors built in, they actually did use tables. a table of 256 numbers for a quadrant of a circle, then flipped and mirrored, could give you 1024 different directions to 'face' in a game, which was often 'good enough'.

Answer (score 41):

You changed very quickly in a comment to MrFatzo's answer to "how do computers calculate $\sin(x)$?", so I'm going to infer that what you're *actually* trying to ask is:

> How does one calculate sines from scratch, without taking anyone's word for the correctness of tables or other magic values that go into the calculation?

I'm aware of two methods:

1. The ancients reckoned sines in degrees rather than radians. They created tables of sine values (actually chord values, in really ancient times, but that more or less amounts to the same problem) by starting with $\sin(0^\circ)=0$, $\sin(90^\circ)=1$ and then using known formulas for $\sin(v/2)$ to find sines of progressively *smaller* angles than $90^\circ$, and then formulas for $\sin(v+u)$ to find sines of sums of these smaller angles. That way they could eventually fill out their entire table.

   In this method calculating a *single* sine from scratch is not really anything you do -- it's not very much less work than creating the entire table, which is to say: years and years of painstaking manual calculations.

   See [How to evaluate trigonometric functions by pen and paper?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757663/how-to-evaluate-trigonometric-functions-by-pen-and-paper) for a bit more detail.
2. In more modern times -- that is, roughly after the development of calculus -- we prefer our sines in radians. Then the gold standard for what the value of a sine should be is the *power series*:
   $$ \sin x = x - \frac16 x^3 + \frac1{120} x^5 - \cdots + \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n+1} + \cdots $$
   This series converges quite fast when $x$ is not larger than a handful of radians, and it is simple to estimate the convergence as you go along (once $2n>x$, the limit will be strictly between any two successive partial sums), so that lets you compute single sines from scratch to any precision you desire.

The power series is still kind of slow even for computers, if you want to compute millions of sines. So *in practice* computers and calculators use various combinations of clever interpolation methods and tables that are built into the hardware. The tables themselves were ultimately constructed using the power series methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will read about this approximations

Comment: And, ok, I tried to calculate $90-90^3/6$, and $90/180*\pi-(90/180*\pi)^3/6$ but I didn't get 0. Why?

Comment: Actually many pieces of hardware, the low end ones in particular, often use [CORDIC-method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC)  instead of power series. No costly divisions, you see. I'm not up to speed what exactly "low end" means here currently. Caveat reader. Oh, another user already made the same remark.

Comment: @ArturKlochko: The power series works for radians, not degrees. So to get the sine of a right angle you should plug in $x=\pi/2$ rather than $x=90$. Just two terms of the series are not enough to get particularly close to $1$, but if you take it up to 4 or 5 terms you should see better agreement.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Yes, that's one of the clever interpolation methods I was alluding to. CORDIC is based on tabulation of a few strategically chosen arctangent values, and I'm assuming that _those_ tables were verified with power series first.

Comment: I understood, thank You

Comment: Ah very cool, I knew about using $\sin(x/2)$ but I never thought of using $\sin(u+v)$ afterwards; it gives infinitely more flexibility.

Answer (score 10):

Use the old-fashioned method: draw a really big circle, add the angle you wish to calculate, and measure.

Comment: I wanted to say something along these lines: Draw something resembling a nice sine curve manually and measure... There are a few known special values which can serve as a scaffolding, and the corresponding first derivations.

Comment: Unit circle is better.  You can draw one cleanly with a compass and don't have to worry about approximation.

Comment: You are right ... makes me wonder whether that was ever used in order to assemble sine tables. With a 10m radius circle drawn with a non-elastic rope you can probably get a <1cm measuring accuracy which would be in the 1E-2 - 1E-3 ballpark.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider : The old logarithm and trig. tables were computed by starting with some circle point $s_1=0.01$ (in reality more like $s_1=10^{-6}$) and $c_1=\sqrt{1-s_1^2}\approx 0.99995$  and then doubling the angle with trig. identities until some landmark is passed, for instance $\sin(30°)=\frac12$. Composing the dyadic powers one finds $n$ with $s_n\le\frac12\le s_{n+1}$ and using interpolation one can then reconstruct what angle the pairs $(c_n,s_n)$ correspond to with an accuracy of of about $1e{-}3$ with IMO less effort than required to draw a perfect 10m circle.

Answer (score 5):

For a remarkably good approximation with relatively little effort, consider [Bhaskara I's sine approximation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhaskara_I's_sine_approximation_formula). For angles in degrees (between 0 and 180), this takes the form
$$
\sin x^\circ \approx \frac{4x(180-x)}{40500-x(180-x)}
$$
while in radians, it's
$$
\sin x \approx \frac{16x(\pi-x)}{5\pi^2-4x(\pi-x)}=\frac{16\frac{x}\pi(1-\frac{x}\pi)}{5-4\frac{x}\pi(1-\frac{x}\pi)}
$$
This expression has a relative error of less than 2%, which occurs for very small (and for very close to 180$^\circ$) angles. The absolute error is never greater than 0.00165.

Comment: Thanks, this one very useful, exactly, what did I ask about

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest a less well-known method that generalises nicely to many other functions and can be quite efficient even when you need to do all the calculations by hand:

The pair $(c,s) = (\cos x, \sin x)$  (in *radians*, of course!) can be interpreted as the unique solution to the ordinary differential equation
$$
  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \begin{pmatrix}c\\s\end{pmatrix}
     = \begin{pmatrix}-s\\c\end{pmatrix}
$$
with starting condition $c(0) = 1$, $s(0) = 0$. As such, it can be solved approximately by [Runge-Kutta solvers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods). The idea is to start from zero and then approach the target value step by step, effectively using a Taylor expansion around each point. Because the steps are small, Taylor expansion converges much faster here than if you directly put in the target value.

Why this is particularly convenient for manual calculation: you can choose the step-lengths in a way so the numbers will stay reasonably nice in decimal, as long as you make sure the steps are small and add up to the point where you want to go.

I'll use the [Heun scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heun%27s_method), which is the simplest of these iterative solvers that actually gives usable precision. It's based on a 2nd order Taylor expansion.

So let's say you want to compute $\sin (45^\circ) = \sin (\tfrac\pi4)$. We know this should come out as $\sqrt2/2$, but let's see. I'll pick 0.2 as the default step-size. Let's go: 
$x_0=0$, $c_0=1$, $s_0=0$

1. $$\begin{align}
         h_1=&0.2 \\ x_1=&0.2
      \\ \tilde c_1 =& c_0 - h_1\times s_0 = 1
      \\ \tilde s_1 =& s_0 + h_1\times c_0 = 0.2
      \\ c_1 =& c_0 - \frac{h_1}2\times (s_0 + \tilde s_1) = 1 - 0.1\times0.2 = 0.98
      \\ s_1 =& s_0 + \frac{h_1}2\times (c_0 + \tilde c_1) = 0.2
     \end{align}$$
2. $$\begin{align}
         h_2=&0.2 \\ x_2=&0.4
      \\ \tilde c_2 =& c_1 - h_2\times s_1 = 0.98 - 0.2\times0.2 = 0.94
      \\ \tilde s_2 =& s_1 + h_2\times c_1 = 0.2 + 0.2\cdot0.98 = 0.396
      \\ c_2 =& c_1 - \frac{h_2}2\times (s_1 + \tilde s_2) = 0.98 - 0.1\times 0.596 = 0.9204
      \\ s_2 =& s_1 + \frac{h_2}2\times (c_1 + \tilde c_2) = 0.2 + 0.1\times 1.92 = 0.392
     \end{align}$$
3. $$\begin{align}
         h_3=&0.2 \\ x_3=&0.6
      \\ \tilde c_3 =& \ldots = 0.9204 - 0.2\times 0.392 = 0.842
      \\ \tilde s_3 =& \ldots = 0.392 + 0.2\times 0.9204 = 0.5768
      \\ c_3 =& \ldots = 0.9204 - 0.1\times 0.9688 = 0.82352
      \\ s_3 =& \ldots = 0.392 + 0.1\times 1.7624 = 0.56824
     \end{align}$$
4. Ok, if we now did another step of 0.2, we'd end up at 0.8, but $\pi/4 \approx 0.7854$. So we'll only do a step of 0.1. Also I'll start rounding after the fifth decimal here.
   $$\begin{align}
         h_4=&0.1 \\ x_4=&0.7
      \\ \tilde c_4 =& \ldots = 0.82352 - 0.1\times 0.56824 \approx 0.76670
      \\ \tilde s_4 =& \ldots = 0.56824 + 0.1\times 0.82352 \approx 0.65059
      \\ c_4 =& \ldots = 0.82352 - 0.05\times 1.21883 \approx 0.76258
      \\ s_4 =& \ldots = 0.56824 + 0.05\times 1.53339 \approx 0.64491
     \end{align}$$
5. $$\begin{align}
         h_5=&0.08 \\ x_5=&0.78
      \\ \tilde c_5 =& \ldots = 0.76258 - 0.08\times 0.64491 \approx 0.71099
      \\ \tilde s_5 =& \ldots = 0.64491 + 0.08\times 0.76258 \approx 0.70592
      \\ c_5 =& \ldots = 0.76258 - 0.04\times 1.47357 \approx 0.70364
      \\ s_5 =& \ldots = 0.64491 + 0.04\times 1.35083 \approx 0.69894
     \end{align}$$

Ok, we're now pretty close to $\tfrac\pi4$, and it's already good to see how the values for $\cos$ and $\sin$ become very similar, since theory says $\sin(\tfrac\pi4) = \cos(\tfrac\pi4) = \tfrac{\sqrt2}2$. We can further confirm this by quickly squaring: $0.70364^2 \approx 0.495$. Reasonably close to $0.5$. Not *great*, but also I only did five not-that-small steps (since the Heun scheme is 2nd order accurate, making the steps a bit smaller would give  really notably better accuracy) and – that's the main advantage – all of them only involved very simple multiplications, because I could choose the step size so it would be convenient, unlike in a direct Taylor-series evaluation.

That is also the basic idea behind the [CORDIC method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC) which was already mentioned in comments. That uses extra properties of sine and cosine to achieve better efficiency, but this is not really needed. Many functions that are defined by an ODE are efficiently evaluated by a Runge-Kutta solver; often the fourth-order version is preferred which gives yet better convergence.

In practice, this method is still only superior to direct Taylor if you need multiple function values. Then it's very good because **a)** you make a table of values as you go along **b)** you compute both sine and cosine, which can then be combined by exploiting the symmetry/periodicity properties.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways in which trig functions are calculated by computers, including rather inaccurate ones (for example the *fsin* method of Intel processors is [notorious](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/10/09/intel-underestimates-error-bounds-by-1-3-quintillion/)). A nice overview of implementations of many  functions can be found [here](https://www.mpfr.org/algorithms.pdf) as part of the GNU [MPFR library](https://www.mpfr.org).

Answer (score 1):

As for how computer actually evaluate sin(x) and other trig / transcendental functions, rather than using the Taylor series, which can converge rather slowly at times, the method usually used is a [Chebyshev Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials).  It should be noted that the whooshing sound you can hear is the mathematics on that page going clean over my head. ;)

That said, you normally extract a relatively small number of coefficients, and use them in a polynomial expansion that gets reasonable accuracy, albeit with a non-zero error term.  This page shows the numbers involved in evaluating [Sin(x)](http://mooooo.ooo/chebyshev-sine-approximation/)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the taylor series or you can use an approximation which I am suggesting, but it will be only useful if you know the value of sin of some nearby angles[image: h is very less than x]

Comment: Worth elaborating. Use various well known values, plus identities to get values for an angle as near as possible. Then an approximation apporach such as Taylor can converge rapidly and be practical.